# Sql Server Varchar(max) and Text Data Types

Tags: sql-server, text, varcharmax

I am researching varchar(max) data type in sql server and I try to compare with text and varchar(8000) datatype. I read several articles about this. As specified in some articles, we cannot  update text column using regular DML statements and instead we need to use updateText, readText, writeText. I tried this in sql server 2008 and I can update text column using reqular DML statements.I wonder, was the situation that specified in articles correct for previous versions of Sql Server? And how does sql server store varchar(max) data if exceeds 8 kb?

Comment: We can update text column with regular dml commands, the articles you read would have incorrect information.

Answer (score 4):

Text datatype is available still just for backwards compatibility. Do not use it, instead use char/varchar/nchar/nvarchar in its place.

As the the limit of varchar it is 2GB.